# Error in localize DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to localize jquery datepicker but since I'm not an expert in jquery I get an error and I don't know how to fix it.

Error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.ui.datepicker.regional')
```

Here is the code of datepicker

**calendar.js**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
  });
    $( ".to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

and the localization

```
<script src="//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3875/branches/labs/datepicker2/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js" ></script>
```

Both of them come after the following code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this Link - **[Datepicker Localize](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)**

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tufd/1/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".from" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "it" ] );
    $( ".to" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "it" ] );
});
```

---

- The file you were referrring was old. [**New link for Localize**](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.20/ui/i18n/).

Use the below script tag for reference.

```
 <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.20/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js" ></script>
```

- You need to include `$.datepicker.regional[ "it" ]` to apply localize settings.

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tufd/3/)

Comment: Yeah...it worked like a charm. Great..one more question. Do you know how to resize the calendar?